# What is the best way to approach a 'How many items do you have selected' type counter?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, checkbox, switch-statement

What I'm meaning is: I have a Table View and Populated Cells, I want each cell, when selected, to link to its on or off state that is represented in its bool value. When it's in an 'On' State, it adds +1 to a counter, when it's clicked to it's 'Off' state it takes back that count (so subtracting). I have the bool within the class that populates the table view so that it doesn’t mix up selections when filtering data via search bar

Imagine a 'How many items do you have selected' type of counter.

What I'm unsure about is how to connect the bool to the selection itself so it’s not ‘mixed up’. Examples are welcome!

Thankyou

Comment: You should have a single datasource that is an array of a custom object (for example, `[Item]`). Each object (could be a struct or class, doesn't matter) can contain a `Bool` that represents whether it's `on` or `off`. Then just set this state when the toggle is triggered (try [using closures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64508719/14351818)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propably easiest solution is using simple variable "counter" and count your selections in `UITableViewDelegate` method `didSelectRowAt` (counting up) and method `didDeselectRowAt` (counting down)

Here are some steps and example code:

1. create `UITableview` and conform your `UIViewController` to `UITableViewDelegate` protocol . Then add methods to your `UIViewController` and conform `yourTableView.delegate = yourViewController` (propably just self).

Adding delegate methods:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.counter += 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.counter -= 1
}
```

Comment: Hello, this is very simple and it worked well, the only thing I needed to add was this line of code to support multiple selections

self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

Comment: @RemBithsWind I am glad I could help. :)

Comment: @RemBithsWind Hi, I see that yesterday my answer was removed from "accepted" , is something wrong with the answer ? Thanks

Comment: @RemBithsWind I understand, however implementing  of `searchBar`was not part of your original question..

Comment: @RemBithsWind Thanks.  Anyway better way for implementing `searchBar`  is storing selected/deselected Bool value  in item itself if (as you did) and then select / deselect cell in `cellForRowAt indexPath:` method. Also do not forget to deselect all cells , once your user starts searching

Answer (score 1):

To approach this question, I would have a custom table view cell. A great tutorial on this is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQYqGM5_wVY&list=LL&index=16&t=752s
It actually shows the use of a switch in a tableview.

To have a counter, I would use UINotification Center. In the custom tableview cell swift file, I would add something like the code below to the action for your switch:

```
if switch.isOn{
   NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name("tableSwitchClicked"), object: nil, userInfo: ["isOn":true]))
} else {
   NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name("tableSwitchClicked"), object: nil, userInfo: ["isOn":false]))
}
```

"switch" is whatever the outlet name of your switch is.
Then add this to your viewcontroller swift file in the viewDidLoad:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(changeSwitchCounter(_:)), name: Notification.Name("tableSwitchClicked"), object: nil)
```

and finally, this in your code after viewDidLoad in the main view controller:

```
@objc func changeSwitchCounter(_ notification: Notification){
   let positiveChange = notification.userInfo!["isOn"] as! Bool
   if positiveChange == true {
      switchOnCount += 1
   } else if positiveChange == false {
      switchOnCount -= 1
   }
   
}
```

where switchOnCount is the variable you use to track the amount of switches on. I hope this helps you! Please comment if you have any questions.